# Reversing a string sentence (not necessarily space between each)

Tags: c#, .net

I have this string:

```
com.example.is-this@myname
```

i would like it to be

```
myname@this-is.example.com
```

using .Net, but a straight out concept or an idea would be good to.

What i'm currently doing is going over each character, find out if it's one of the "special characters" and assign all prior chars, to a variable of an array, at the end, i'm joining them all together from last to first.

is there a possible more efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With little bit of Regex and Linq this is fairly simple.

Idea is that we take words and non word characters as separate token with Regex patten. Then, we just reverse it and join it.

```
var tokens =  Regex.Matches("com.example.is-this@myname", @"\w+|\W")
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(x=>x.Value)
.Reverse();

string reversed = string.Concat(tokens);
```

Output: [Ideone - Demo](http://ideone.com/fDfiN6)

```
myname@this-is.example.com
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

This is the classic word-by-word reversal, with a small twist on delimiters. A solution to this problem is reversing each word individually, and then reversing the whole string. Do not touch delimiters when reversing words.

First step goes as follows: we find limits of each token, and reverse it in place, like this:

1. com.example.is-this@myname
2. moc.example.is-this@myname
3. moc.elpmaxe.is-this@myname
4. moc.elpmaxe.si-this@myname
5. moc.elpmaxe.si-siht@myname
6. moc.elpmaxe.si-siht@emanym

Reverse the result to get your desired output:

```
moc.elpmaxe.si-siht@emanym -> myname@this-is.example.com
```

As far as the implementation goes, you can do it by converting the string to an array of characters to make it changeable in place, and write a short helper method that lets you reverse a portion of a `char` array between indexes `i` and `j`. With this helper method in place, all you need to do is to find delimiters and call the helper for each delimited word, and then make one final call to reverse the entire sentence.

Comment: This threw me for a moment, but I like it. Combined with @Erick's answer to split the string in its tokens on the delimiters, it makes for a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Split` C# method.

The example below is from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split).

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "there is a cat";
        // Split string on spaces.
        // ... This will separate all the words.
        string[] words = s.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Is as simple as examples get.

Then you add more conditions to your `Split()`

```
string [] split = strings .Split(new Char [] {'.' , '@', '-' }, 
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The `RemoveEmptyEntries` just removes unwanted empty entries to your array.

After that you reverse your array using the `Array.Reverse` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And then you can stitch your string back together with a Foreach loop.

As [@marjan-venema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11225/marjan-venema) mentioned in the comments you could populate a parallel array at this point with each delimiter. Reverse it, and then concatenate the string when you are using the Foreach loop at each entry.

Comment: how do you stitch it back when you don't know which delimiters were where?

Comment: Have a parallel array and fill it with the original sequence in which you encounter the delimiters. Reverse that and use it in stitching the string back.

Comment: What @dasblinkenlight mentioned seems to be a lot more feasible.

Comment: you really need a combination of your answer and his. He doesn't talk about how to find limits of each token. yours does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it using a `List`, which has a handy `Insert` method, as well as a `Reverse` method.

The `Insert` method lets you continue to add characters to the same index in the list (and the others after it are moved to higher indexes).

So, as you read the original string, you can keep inserting the characters at the start. Once you come to a delimeter, you add it to the end and adjust your insert position to be right after the delimeter.

When you're done, you just call `Reverse` and join the characters back to a string:

```
public static string ReverseWords(string words, char[] wordDelimeters)
{
    var reversed = new List<char>();
    int insertPosition = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        var character = words[i];

        if (wordDelimeters.Contains(character))
        {
            reversed.Add(character);
            insertPosition = i + 1;
            continue;
        }

        reversed.Insert(insertPosition, character);
    }

    reversed.Reverse();
    return string.Join("", reversed);        
}
```